# batch file to detect if wifi adapter is enabled

Tags: cmd, wifi, netsh

I tried to complete this commands in cmd but im having trouble fixing it. Can anyone help me?

```
netsh wlan show networks | FIND "turned off" /I /C
if "dont know what should be here" == 0 (
echo   enabled
) else (
echo  disabled
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `%errorlevel%` variable, which indicates the exit status of the command last executed (in your case `find`). You have to revert your logic, though, because find returns 0 (i.e. "success") when the adapter is disabled. Also, I'd recommend to do a numeric comparison (`equ`) instead of a string comparison (`==`).

```
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
  echo disabled
) else (
  echo enabled
)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is attempt to enable it whether or not it's enabled or disabled

netsh interface set interface name="name of adapter" admin=enable || echo already enabled

If the adapter is already enabled then it won't do anything so the double pipes || means if there's an error in the first command it will execute whatever command is after it which is echo "already enabled."

If it says "this network connection does not exist" ignore that, it means the adapter is already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I put together this code for a batch script. It works like a charm to turn ON/OFF my wireless network connection:

```
netsh wlan show networks | FIND "Wireless network connection" /I /C
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (wmic path win32_networkadapter where NetConnectionID="Conexión de red inalámbrica" call enable) else (wmic path win32_networkadapter where NetConnectionID="Wireless network connection" call disable)
```

If you have more than one wireless network connection, change the name for your particular network connection name and that will do.